# Sign apps without an Apple-ID paired to a device for two step verification

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-id

I've got an Apple-ID for personal use and one for my professional use, which I sign my apps with. Now Apple requires to have two step authorisation switched on (not to be confused with 2 factor authorisation). This requires to have one of your devices paired with your professional Apple-ID to sign in with Xcode and sign the apps.
Since I have both my iPhone and MacBook paired with my personal AppleID, I cannot sign my apps anymore.

I've tried switching accounts on my MacBook, sign an app en switch back, but this does not last. It's too much hassle to do this every time I need to sign an app.

Is there something I could do to make this easier? I can imagine I'm not the only one having this issue..

Thanks,

Bart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using 2-step verification, you should upgrade to 2-factor authentication. If you can't upgrade to 2-factor, you can receive 2-step verification codes via SMS, which should not require your device to be signed in to the developer account.

Have a look at the following support article: https://developer.apple.com/support/account/authentication/. The following answers under the "More Information" heading might be particularly relevant to your case, but be sure to read the whole article.

> **How can I use different Apple IDs for iCloud and my Apple Developer account?** If your personal Apple ID is different from the Apple ID
>   associated with your Apple Developer account, you can configure your
>   device to allow verification codes to be received for both Apple IDs.
>
> - **If your Apple IDs are already enabled for two-factor authentication:**
>     On your iOS device Add your developer Apple ID to your device running
>     iOS 12 or later at Settings > Passwords & Accounts > Add Account >
>     iCloud. Your device is now set up to receive verification codes for
>     both your personal and developer Apple IDs. On your Mac Add your
>     developer Apple ID to your Mac running OS X El Capitan or later at
>     System Preferences > Internet Accounts > iCloud. Your Mac is now set
>     up to receive verification codes for both your personal and developer
>     Apple IDs.
> - **If your Apple IDs are not yet enabled for two-factor
>     authentication:** On your iOS device Enable two-factor authentication
>     for your personal Apple ID at Settings > iCloud > Password & Security > Two-Factor Authentication. Sign out of iCloud on your iOS device at Settings > iCloud > Sign Out. Sign in to iCloud on your device with
>     your developer Apple ID. Enable two-factor authentication for your
>     developer Apple ID at Settings> iCloud > Password & Security >
>     Two-Factor Authentication. Sign in to iCloud on your iOS device with
>     your personal Apple ID. Add your developer Apple ID to your device at
>     Settings > Passwords & Accounts > Add Account > iCloud. Your device is
>     now set up to receive verification codes for both your personal and
>     developer Apple IDs. On your Mac  Enable two-factor authentication for
>     your personal Apple ID at System Preferences > iCloud > Account
>     Details > Security. Create a new system account on your Mac for your
>     developer Apple ID at System Preferences > Users & Groups. Sign in to
>     your new developer system account and enable two-factor authentication
>     for your developer Apple ID at System Preferences > iCloud > Account
>     Details > Security. Sign in to your primary system account and add
>     your developer Apple ID to your Mac at System Preferences > Internet
>     Accounts > iCloud. Your Mac is now set up to receive verification
>     codes for your personal and developer Apple IDs on your primary user
>     account. You can also receive verification codes for multiple Apple
>     IDs via text message or phone call to your trusted phone number rather
>     than through iCloud.
>
> **What if I’ve enabled two-step verification?**
>   If your Apple ID has
>   two-step verification enabled and two-factor authentication is
>   available in your country or region, you will need to update to
>   two-factor authentication for increased security.
>
> **Can I use the same trusted phone number for multiple Apple IDs?** Yes.
>   You can assign the same trusted phone number to multiple Apple IDs
>   that you use.

There's more info on 2-step verification here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204152, which might be helpful if you can't upgrade to 2-factor.